# Makefile beginner help

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile, g++, setup-project, gnu

I am trying to learn Makefiles. I have done some small project that works but now im extending it but getting no luck. Here is the question. I am trying to compile all the files from subdirs and then store them in build/objects directory (which i cannot get to work) and link the binary to the files in the build/objects directory. Here is what i have gotten so far:

```
#compiler vars
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS= 


#build vars
INCLUDE=-I. -IFramework/ -IGame/
SOURCES=test.cpp

include Modules.mk
ifeq ($(mod3D), true)
SOURCES += $(mod3D_src)
INCLUDE += $(mod3D_include)
endif

ifeq ($(mod2D), true)
SOURCES += $(mod2D_src)
INCLUDE += $(mod2D_include)
endif

ifeq ($(modInput), true)
SOURCES += $(modInput_src)
INCLUDE += $(modInput_include)
endif

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
OUTPUT=game.bin

all: $(SOURCES) $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o: $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    -rm $(OUTPUT) $(OBJECTS)
```

Modules.mk

```
#Modules
mod3D=true
mod2D=true
modInput=true

mod3D_include=-IGraphics3D
mod2D_include=-IGraphics2D
modInput_include=-IInput

mod3D_src=Graphics3D/*.cpp
mod2D_src=#Graphics2D/*.cpp
modInput_src=Input/*.cpp
```

it gives me error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Graphics3D/*.o', needed by `game.bin'.  Stop.
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance,
Gasim

Answer (score 0):

Your use of wildcards in forming prerequisites is wrong.

Have a look at this section of the GNU make manual:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Pitfall

Answer (score 0):

The fix is pretty simple:

```
mod3D_src = $(wildcard Graphics3D/*.cpp)
# and likewise:
mod2D_src = # $(wildcard Graphics2D/*.cpp)
modInput_src = $(wildcard Input/*.cpp)
```